# Node js express with socket, index and server files seperated

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to add to my express server a socket listener, but separating server.js inits and index.js REST calls. I really struggled with getting things together with adding the socket.

my server.js

```
const express = require("express");
const socket = require("socket.io");

class Server {
  constructor() {
    this.app = express();
    this.port = 4000;
    this.paths = { app: "/app" };

    this.middlewares();
    this.routes();

    this.socket_listen = socket(this.server,{ 
      cors: {
        origin: 'http://localhost:3000'
      }
    });

  }

  routes() {
    this.app.use(this.paths.app, require("../routes/app"));
  }

  listen() {
    this.server = this.app.listen(this.port);
  }

}

module.exports = Server;
```

my app.js

```
const Server = require('./models/server');
const server = new Server();

server.listen();
```

my index.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
const {Server} = require('../models/server.js')

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    return res.status(400);
});


Server.socket_listen.on('connection', function(socket) {
    console.log('A user connected');

    //Whenever someone disconnects this piece of code executed
    socket.on('disconnect', function () {
       console.log('A user disconnected');
    });
});



module.exports = router;
```

The router option works great, but the socket throws me an errors, and i couldn't understand how to connect them correctly.

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'socket_listen')

Comment: "an errors" isn't useful information, but in general, `Server#constructor()` depends on `this.server` to exist, but that only gets created in `Server#listen()` (which you don't call at all anyway).

Answer (score 1):

i think the problem is that in the index.js you are calling the Server class instead of a server class instance.
For simplicity try creating everything in te index.js and later you can separate it in different files.
If you want to separate it into different files or classes you shloud respect the order in which the code is excecuting in this example.

index.js

```
const http = require("http");
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
    
const app = express();
    
//settings
app.set('port', 8080);
app.use(bodyParser.json());
    
const server = http.createServer(app);
const PORT = app.get('port');
    
server.listen(PORT);

const io = require("socket.io")(server, {
    cors: {
        //set origin urls
        origin: [],
        // set allow headers
        allowHeaders: [],
        //idk what is this
        credentials: true
    }
});

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello world')
});

io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    console.log('A user connected');
    
    //Whenever someone disconnects this piece of code executed
    socket.on('disconnect', function () {
       console.log('A user disconnected');
    });
});
```